# VSC visibility issues

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: screenshot]
On the left there was a panel with a lot of options. It isn't just ctrl+B.
For example access to github etc.

On the top there was an activity bar with the buttom to modify the layout of the panels.

I touched a little bit too much of visibility option and I can't retrieve anything.
in particular I can't push to github things from VSC.

Is there a way to retrieve the activity bar on the top?
Just that is enough to show stuff when I need it

Comment: show full screenshot. are you in zen mode? if this is just an issue of settings changes, just open your settings.json file and remove the settings changes that you no longer want.

Comment: i found alt shoortcut. This solved my issue

Comment: what alt shortcut? what was the problem?

Comment: If I use alt, it shows stuff on the top. From there i retrieved everything